# Calculate a quadratic irrational from its periodic continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I have a periodic continued fraction [2; 1, 3] and I want to convert it into a quadratic irrational.

Any helps?

Comment: Is that $(2;\overline{1,3})$ or $(2;1,\overline{3})$?

Answer (score 1):

$x=(1;\overline{3,1})\implies x=1+\cfrac1{3+\cfrac1x}\implies3x^2-3x-1=0$. Thus,
$$
(1;\overline{3,1})=\frac{3+\sqrt{21}}6
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
(2;\overline{1,3})
&=2+\frac6{3+\sqrt{21}}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{1+\sqrt{21}}2
\end{align}
$$

---

$x=(3;\overline{3})\implies x=3+\cfrac1x\implies x^2-3x-1=0$. Thus,
$$
(3;\overline{3})=\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}2
$$
Therefore,
$$
(2;1,\overline{3})=\frac{13+\sqrt{13}}6
$$

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: From [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeriodicContinuedFraction.html), you can use the formula 
$$[a,b] = \frac{-ab+\sqrt{ab(ab+4)}}{2a}.$$

Then, you can check the result [here](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/CONTFRAC.HTM) with $\frac{1+\sqrt{21}}{2}$